# How to fix missing directories in a new Jekyll site

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll

I finally got all my Ruby issues squared away and have Jekyll installed. When I run `jekyll new sitename` it creates a new Jekyll project and doesn't show any errors, but the project is missing several directories including `_includes`, `_layouts`, `_sass`.

When I browse to the site on my localhost, however, it shows a working site.  The `_site` folder has a CSS file in the assets folder.

Every tutorial I've seen shows that those missing directories I list above should be created when the project is initialized, but this is my first time working with Jekyll, so I can't tell if I'm missing something.

Does anyone know what would cause the site to be incomplete or for these directories to be hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll 3.2.0 introduced **gem based themes**:

> Our flagship feature for this release has been themes. Themes?!, you
>   say? Yes, proper, versionable, releasable, first-class themes. We’re
>   pretty stoked about it and we hope you like building and using them.
>   For now, it only supports layouts, includes, and sass, but we have
>   plans to include static assets like images and CSS/JS in a future
>   release.

That basically means that by default you won't have these typical directories:

```
/assets
/_layouts
/_includes
/_sass
```

But you can always overwrite them or copy to your jekyll instance to [modify them](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/).

Comment: Ah, gotcha marcanuy.  That explains a lot because it seemed like everything was working just fine and I had a sinking suspicion that I was missing something.  Thanks!